# C++ Class constructor usage

Tags: c++, class, constructor, definition

I am creating a C++ program to implement the Gale-Shapely matching algorithm but I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with my class constructor. I am following the guidelines I have found but Visual Code will keep giving me generic error messages about it and does not seem to recognize me as having defined the two arrays I define under the constructor.

This is the file for the class I created:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <time.h>       
using namespace std

class matcher {

private:
    string male[10][10];
    string fmale[10][10];
    //to adapt this code to a random size of members, any mention of the array index size (such as [10] will have to replaced with a new variable)
public:   
    matcher(string x[10], string y[10]){
        for( int i = 0; i < 9; i ++){
            male[i][0] = x[i];
            fmale[i][0] = y[i];
        }
        //populates the male and female 2d arrays with the given arrays of names
        srand (time(NULL));
        //attempting to seed the random generator with the time value
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int used[10];
            //array of used indexes, so we dont have the same name twice on a preference list
            for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
                randval = rand() % 9;
                //random index between 0 and 9
                while(!(find(used[0], used[9], randval))){
                    male[i][z] = y[randval];
                    //gives the male a new prefernce at the random index from the list of females
                } 
            }
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int used[10];
            for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
                randval = rand() % 9;
                while(!(find(used[0], used[9], randval))){
                    fmale[i][z] = x[randval];
                } 
            }
        }
        //similar operation, except adapted for the female list
    }

    void generateMatches(string x[10][10],string y[10][10]){
        stack <string> unMat;
        //stack of strings, males to be matched
        string matches[10][1]
        for(i = (length(x)) - 1), i <= 0, i++){
            unMat.emplace(x[i]);
        } 
        //places the list of males on the stack to be matched
        while (!unMat.empty()){
            string curr = unMat.top();
            //Assign the top unmatched male to the current string 
            indCurr = find(std::begin(male[0][0]), std::end(male[9][0]), curr);
            int xCurr = indCurr % 10;
            int yCUrr = indCirr / 10;

            //finds the index of the unmatched top male and assigns so we can traverse the array to find the males pref
            while(!(find(std::begin(male[xCurr][0]), std::end(male[xCurr][9]), NULL)))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10. i++){
                    if(male[xCurr][i] == NULL){
                        //if this current index in the male preference is NULL, it means there has already been an unsuccessful matching attempt
                        //So this female was removed so that he will not propose to her
                        break;
                    }
                    if(int indV = find(std::begin(matches[0][1]), std::end(mathces[9][1]), male[ind][i])){
                    //checks to see if the list of matches rreturns a valid index for the name, meaning it is a matched female.
                        int fxMatches = indv % 10;
                        int fyMatches = indv / 10;
                        //1d to 2d conversion, index of female on the matching list
                        int mxMatches = fxMatches;
                        int myMatches = 0;
                        string nameOfMatchedMale = matches[mxMatches][myMatches];
                        //giving us the name of the male matched to the female we are currently looking at
                        string nameOfFemale = male[ind][i];
                        //getting the name of the female we are going to have our current male propose to
                        int indx = find(fmale[0][0], fmale[9][0], nameOfFemale);
                        //finds the index of this female on the female list
                        int fx = indx % 10;
                        int fy = indx / 10;
                        //id to 2d conversion
                        int indMale = find(fmale[fx][1], fmale[fx][9], nameOfMatchedMale);
                        int indMale2 = find(fmale[fx][1],fmale[fx][9], curr);
                        if(indMale > indMale2){
                            //this means current male is ranked better than the matched male, so he will propose successfuly
                            unMat.pop();
                            //removing the current male from the unmatches stack
                            matches[mxMatches][myMatches] = curr;
                            //we will place him as the females new match, and add the unmatched male to the stack
                            unMat.emplace(nameOfMatchedMale);
                            //adding the newly unmatched male to the stack
                            cout<<curr;
                            cout<<" Proposes to ";
                            cout<<male[xCurr][i]<<endl;
                            cout<<"She accepts"<<endl;
                            male[xCurr][i] = NULL;
                            //removing the female from the current males preferences to ensure we cannot be matches again

                            //**********Still needing printing of these events happening************
                            }
                        else{
                            cout<<curr;
                            cout<<" Proposes to ";
                            cout<<male[xCurr][i]<<endl;
                            cout<<"She rejects him :("<<endl;
                            male[xCurr][i] = NULL;
                            //current male will propose unsuccesfully, we will replace this female in his preference list as NULL, and then he will try another
                            }
                        }
                    else{
                        int iz = 0;
                        while(!match[iz][0] == NULL){
                            i++;
                        }

                        //Need to find a way to see the next open index in the matches list
                        match[iz][0] = curr;
                        match[iz][1] = male[ind][i];
                        cout<<curr;
                        cout<<" Proposes to ";
                        cout<<male[xCurr][i]<<endl;
                        cout<<"She Accepts"<<endl;

                        //add current male and female to matches
                        male[xCurr][i] = NULL;
                        //always remove this female from the male preferances so he will not attempt proposol to her again
                    }
                }   
            }   
        }
        cout<<"These are the complete matches:"<<endl;
        for(int i = 0;i < 10, i ++){
            cout<<matches[i][0];
            cout<<" and ";
            cout<<matches[i][1]<<endl;
            //prints all of the matches
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < 9; i ++){
            matches[i][0] = NULL;
            matches[i][1] = NULL;
            /*resets the matching array so that a part of an earlier function, which checks
            the contents of the array to find empty space can work properly*/
        }
    }
```

This is the Main:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "matcher.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string xz[10] = {'abe','bbe','cbe','dbe','ebe','fbe','gbe','hbe','ibe','jbe'};
    string yz[10] = {'kbe','lbe','mbe','nbe','obe','pbe','qbe','rbe','sbe','tbe'};
    matcher newSort(xz,yz);
    string answer = "y";
    while(answer == "y" ){
        newSort.generateMatches();
        cout << "would you like to redo the match ( Y:yes, N:no )? " << endl;
        cin>>answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the "generic error messages"? Are these messages truly from your IDE (typically updated as you type), or are they from your compiler (given when you build/try to run)? Your compiler is likely to give a more useful error message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this compiles:

```
string xz[10] = {'abe','bbe','cbe','dbe','ebe','fbe','gbe','hbe','ibe','jbe'};
string yz[10] = {'kbe','lbe','mbe','nbe','obe','pbe','qbe','rbe','sbe','tbe'};
matcher newSort(xz, yz);
```

But this will:

```
string xz[10] = { "abe","bbe","cbe","dbe","ebe","fbe","gbe","hbe","ibe","jbe" };
string yz[10] = { "kbe","lbe","mbe","nbe","obe","pbe","qbe","rbe","sbe","tbe" };
matcher newSort(xz, yz);
```

Comment: The first compiles because `'abe'`  and the rest are multi-character literals - which have type `char` but implementation-defined values - , and (C++11 and later) `std::string` has a constructor that accepts an initialiser list